# How to style features created by DrawFeature control?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I've been following this tutorial:
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoext_client.html#select-the-start-and-final-destination

It contains an Openlayers.Control.DrawFeatures control defined in the following code sample. You can also see the lines where the author comments *"if we want to apply a special style to the start point we should do this here"*. Problem is: I don't know how to apply a style in this setting and cannot find any examples using DrawFeatures control in this way.

How can I have the start point use a different style than the end point using this DrawFeatures control?

```
DrawPoints = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature, {

// this control is active by default
autoActivate: true,

initialize: function(layer, options) {
    // only points can be drawn
    var handler = OpenLayers.Handler.Point;
    OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.prototype.initialize.apply(
            this, [layer, handler, options]
        );
},

drawFeature: function(geometry) {
    OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.prototype.drawFeature.apply(
            this, arguments 
        );
    if (this.layer.features.length == 1) {
        // we just draw the startpoint
        // note: if we want to apply a special style to the 
        //       start point we should do this here
    } else if (this.layer.features.length == 2) {
        // we just draw the finalpoint
        // note: if we want to apply a special style to the 
        //       final point we should do this here

        // we have all what we need; we can deactivate ourself.
        this.deactivate();            
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add these lines and modify them to suit your style:

```js
...
    if (this.layer.features.length == 1) {
        // we just draw the startpoint
        // note: if we want to apply a special style to the 
        //       start point we should do this here

        var myFirstPointStyle = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(myFirstPointStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
        myFirstPointStyle.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        myFirstPointStyle.strokeWidth = 2;
        myFirstPointStyle.fillColor = "#ffffff";
        this.layer.features[this.layer.features.length - 1].style = myFirstPointStyle;

        this.layer.redraw();

    } else if (this.layer.features.length == 2) {
        // we just draw the finalpoint
        // note: if we want to apply a special style to the 
        //       final point we should do this here
        var mySecondPointStyle = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(mySecondPointStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
        mySecondPointStyle.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        mySecondPointStyle.strokeWidth = 7;
        mySecondPointStyle.pointRadius = 12;
        mySecondPointStyle.fillColor = "#000000";
        this.layer.features[this.layer.features.length - 1].style = mySecondPointStyle;

        this.layer.redraw();


        // we have all what we need; we can deactivate ourself.
        this.deactivate();
    }
...
```

This will copy the default style and you can modify it from there. You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Seems like calling redraw() is the key here. I never tried that :)

Comment: You're welcome, it's always rewarding to help out a master :)

Comment: Thanks a lot as it solved my problem too which was related to the application of styles