# Reset style of a vector layer after features are added

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have created two Openlayers vector layers, named "temp" and "drawings1". Each of the layer have different styles. The problem is when I copy a features from drawings1 to temp, the style of "drawings1" is also copied to the "temp" layer. It seems that the pre-configured style of the temp layer is ignored. Is there anyway to reset the style of a vector layer?

```
//Define a style for the drawings1 layer and temp layer 
var highlight_style = { fillColor:'blue', strokeColor:'#2E2EFE', fillOpacity:0.6 };
var hover_style = { fillColor:'#FF0000', strokeColor:'#FF0000', fillOpacity:0.6 };

//Initialize a vector layer for storing selection Objects
drawings1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selections", {isBaseLayer:false, features:[], visibility:true, style:highlight_style}
        );

//Initialize a vector layer for storing selection Objects
temp = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hover", {isBaseLayer:false, features:[], visibility:true, style:hover_style}
        );

map.addLayers([drawings1,temp])

//Copy a feature from drawings1 to temp
tempFeature = drawings1.features[0];
temp.addFeatures(tempFeature);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the problem of the layer styles, but the matter of javascript object reference assignment. By doing this:

```
tempFeature = drawings1.features[0];  // Here you are not copying the feature, but referencing the same feature with a new variable name.
temp.addFeatures(tempFeature);
```

You are not actually copying an feature, but referencing the same feature with a different variable name (tempFeature), which means you are adding the same feature to two layers. And that will cause some style messes.

A simple fix is to use the `clone` method coming with the feature object (almost all openlayers objects have this method).

```
tempFeature = drawings1.features[0].clone(); // Clone the feature which will create a new object.
temp.addFeatures(tempFeature);
```

Comment: Many Thanks.Now a new features is created on the temp layer. However, it is still applying the style of the drawings1 layer. How do I reset style?

Comment: Do you have an public available page that I can visit?

Comment: Sorry the application is web based but for internal use. There is no public web page for this web application. I think I am having the same problem mentioned in this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46730/openlayers-cloned-features-get-style-from-original-feature. I am going to try the solutions suggested in this post.